# Calculate daily percent change in mysql

Tags: mysql

Given the ff sample table:

| DATE | SYMBOL | CLOSING_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | ABC | 100 |
| 2022-08-01 | CDE | 50 |
| 2022-08-01 | XYZ | 10 |
| 2022-08-02 | ABC | 125 |
| 2022-08-02 | CDE | 40 |
| 2022-08-02 | XYZ | 15 |
| 2022-08-03 | ABC | 150 |
| 2022-08-03 | CDE | 50 |
| 2022-08-03 | XYZ | 20 |

I want to make a query that will output the following result:

| DATE | SYMBOL | DAILY_CHANGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | ABC | - |
| 2022-08-01 | CDE | - |
| 2022-08-01 | XYZ | - |
| 2022-08-02 | ABC | 25% |
| 2022-08-02 | CDE | -20% |
| 2022-08-02 | XYZ | 50% |
| 2022-08-03 | ABC | 20% |
| 2022-08-03 | CDE | 20% |
| 2022-08-03 | XYZ | 33.33% |

My data is from the crypto market so there are no gaps between dates. I was planning on expanding to other asset classes like stocks so there will be gaps. Was wondering how would i also deal with that?

Comment: please clarify what you want to do if there are gaps. Do you want to calculate the change since the last entry or just present as null? Or something else

Comment: If there are gaps just null, i guess

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet to achieve what you have asked.

```
SELECT DATE, SYMBOL, 
       (CLOSING_PRICE - LAG(CLOSING_PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY DATE)) / LAG(CLOSING_PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY SYMBOL ORDER BY DATE) AS DAILY_CHANGE
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```